# My First Android app won't run correctly in my Android Device (Mobile Phone)

Tags: java, android

My code is out of errors and I'm trying to run the app with `Samsung Android` device. My device seems to be online and Android version number is `4.2.2`. When the app runs on mobile phone, there's only message dialog telling `The TestiHello is stopped`. `TestiHello` is my project name for simple Hello World -example.

My Eclipse Console stands for next:

```
2014-05-07 22:18:32 - TestiHello] ------------------------------
[2014-05-07 22:18:32 - TestiHello] Android Launch!
[2014-05-07 22:18:32 - TestiHello] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-07 22:18:32 - TestiHello] Performing com.example.testihello.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-07 22:18:32 - TestiHello] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-05-07 22:18:38 - TestiHello] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-05-07 22:18:38 - TestiHello] Starting activity com.example.testihello.MainActivity on device 4203c169c8831100
[2014-05-07 22:18:38 - TestiHello] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.testihello/.MainActivity }
```

I'm using `Samsung Galaxy Trend` phone and Eclipse Indigo on 32bit Windows Vista. My mobile phone is rooted and I'm superuser and have opened USB -debugging mode on it succesfully. Any ideas? My Hypothesis is that problem got something to do with the Android version numbers? Am I Right?

Edit:

```
01-02 06:24:16.830: D/dalvikvm(5212): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-02 06:24:17.030: E/FragmentManager(5212): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.testihello:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{415f01b8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
01-02 06:24:17.030: E/FragmentManager(5212): Activity state:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):   Local FragmentActivity 415cc888 State:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     mLoadersStarted=false
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):   Active Fragments in 415cd978:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{415f01b8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{415cd978 in MainActivity{415cc888}}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       mActivity=com.example.testihello.MainActivity@415cc888
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):   Added Fragments:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{415f01b8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):   FragmentManager misc state:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     mActivity=com.example.testihello.MainActivity@415cc888
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@415ce2a0
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):   View Hierarchy:
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{415d42d0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):       android.widget.LinearLayout{415d5ea8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{415d6b78 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020446 android:id/action_bar_container}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{415d7330 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020447 android:id/action_bar}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):             android.widget.LinearLayout{415df6a0 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{415e0fa0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                 android.widget.ImageView{415e1768 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102028a android:id/up}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                 android.widget.ImageView{415e2738 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):               android.widget.LinearLayout{415e4330 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                 android.widget.ImageView{415e4778 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102028a android:id/up}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{415e4b60 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                   android.widget.TextView{415e50d8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102029f android:id/action_bar_title}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):                   android.widget.TextView{415e7680 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #10202a0 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{415ea320 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020448 android:id/action_context_bar}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):         android.widget.FrameLayout{415eaaf0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):           android.widget.TextView{415f0668 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/FragmentManager(5212):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{415eafe8 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020449 android:id/split_action_bar}
01-02 06:24:17.030: D/AndroidRuntime(5212): Shutting down VM
01-02 06:24:17.030: W/dalvikvm(5212): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c8b930)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testihello/com.example.testihello.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.testihello:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{415f01b8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.testihello:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{415f01b8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
01-02 06:24:17.040: E/AndroidRuntime(5212):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You didn't post the relevant parts of the logcat.

Comment: @ZouZou this isn't even the logcat but the console output. Please replace that with the errors from the logcat.

Comment: Sorry about that... I uploaded Logcat -log -txt file to the my public Onedrive -folder at https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=78EABE0D904CA952&resid=78EABE0D904CA952%21105&authkey=AICAQZA8o2CIJxM  (LogCat_TestiHello_log.txt)

Comment: looks like your layout does not contain the container id for placing the fragment.

Comment: Next we need to see some code. Can you post the code for your Activity class?

Answer (score 1):

Your LogCat logs that you it can't find a view who's id is `container` (it's the default id of the `activity_main.xml` file) for a PlaceHolderFragment. If your code is in your MainActivity, and not in the PlaceHolderFragment, then you can try this:

If you have this in your onCreate() method of your MainActivity, delete it:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

If you don't need the PlaceHolderFragment, you can delete this part of your code as well:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer! After deleting the "if" -statement you told, the app run well!